# How to use Magic Eden instruction endpoints and turn them into transactions in solana-py

Tags: transactions, python, magiceden, solana.py, solana-py

I want to start interacting with Magic Eden NFTs through my solana-py code. So I want to learn how to use the endpoints at https://api.magiceden.dev/#82874536-9430-4dae-81dc-1235baaa3ef3. I have an API key I just want to know the process of building the URL and decoding and signing the transaction. Thanks in advance!